# Read SMS using Broadband or GSM in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sms, serial-port

Anybody here have an idea how to read SMS in SIM using VB.NET? I'm using a Broadband Modem. I can already send SMS, but I can't find out how to read SMS from the SIM and display in  a `datagridview`.

Here is my code to send SMS:

```
SerialPort1.Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
SerialPort1.Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
SerialPort1.Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & num & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
SerialPort1.Write(message & Chr(26))
```

How about reading SMS?

Many thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

maybe a better way is to use a library for sending/receiving sms:
http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm#gsmcomm_download

we used this one and it works pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog entry](http://www.developershome.com/sms/cmgrCommand2.asp) the sequence of commands is

`AT+CMGF=1`  select SMS text modem

`AT+CPMS="SM"` select messagestore (in this case SIM)

`AT+CMGR=1` to actually read the message @ index 1

But be sure to visit the blog, it's a lot more detailed than the short form instructions I gave here.  Also, it's always best to first test out these sequences in Hyperterminal and have a detailed look at the returned data.

A full list of AT commands can be found in many places, [this description of the Nokia AT command set](http://amber.feld.cvut.cz/user/pokorny/bpdp/Nokia_AT.PDF) but which should be quite similar tot your modem is just one possible source.  Of course the manual that comes with your specific modem type is always best, but detailed info like this is quite often not included in the box.

Another thing: you should always check the return values of each AT command (in most cases `OK` or the piece of info you requested) because if you just fire off the entire sequence of commands any error the modem may have sent will pass unnoticed.  Also, I've encountered several modems that don't appreciate being sent to while they're treating the previous command.